# VBA: Querying data in dynamic named range

Tags: vba, adodb

1. I create named range that covers data I need to query using ADODB

   ```
   SourceWB.Names.Add Name:=SOME_RANGE_NAME, RefersTo:=SOME_RANGE
   ```
2. I setup a connection run SQL query

   ```
   sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sSourceName_ & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES"";" 
   Set oConn_ = New ADODB.Connection
   oConn_.Open sConn

   Dim oRs As New ADODB.Recordset
   oRs.Open sSQL, oConn_, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
   ```

The SQL query is

```
SELECT * FROM [SOME_RANGE_NAME] WHERE ....
```

The problem is: these commands are in cycle, where every time there may be other range referenced by SOME_RANGE_NAME. If the range is changing within one sheet, everything is ok. As soon the SOME_RANGE_NAME references range in other sheet I get the following error:

> no value given for one or more required parameters

Answer (score 0):

The solution was proper closing of connections!